# OpenGL diffuse lighting calculates wrong

Tags: c++, opengl, lighting

I have simple scene that involves a rotating cube and a directional (diffuse) light source, but I don't seem to get the lighting math right.

I load the vertices and normals from the obj file from [this](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-7-model-loading/) tutorial:

Some of my application code:

```
glm::mat4 modelview = ...

glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(60.0f, 16.0f/9.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);

glm::mat4 MVP = projection * modelview;
glm::mat3 NormalMatrix = glm::transpose(glm::inverse(glm::mat3(modelview)));

glUniformMatrix4fv(MVP_location, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
glUniformMatrix3fv(NormalMatrix_location, 1, GL_FALSE, &NormalMatrix[0][0]);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 430

in vec3 position;
in vec3 in_normal;
uniform mat4 MVP;
uniform mat3 NormalMatrix;

out vec3 Normal;
out vec4 Color;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(position, 1.0);

    Color = vec4(clamp(position, 0.0, 1.0), 1.0); //based on vertex position
    Normal = normalize(NormalMatrix * in_normal);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 430

const vec3 Ambient = vec3(0.15, 0.15, 0.15);
const vec3 LightDirection = normalize(vec3(1.0, 0.0, 1.0));
const vec3 LightColor = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

const float Shininess = 20.0;
const float Strength = 5.0;

in vec3 Normal;
in vec4 Color;

out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = Color;

    float diffuse = max(0.0, dot(Normal, LightDirection));

    vec3 scatteredLight = Ambient + LightColor * diffuse;

    vec3 rgb = min(FragColor.rgb * scatteredLight, vec3(1.0));

    FragColor = vec4(rgb, Color.a);
}
```

This is what I get:
[my fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Wot7.png)

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `normal` is in view-space, while `LightDirection` is in world-space.

Comment: I added this to my application code:
glm::vec3 light_direction = glm::mat3(modelview) * glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(program, "light_direction"), 1, &light_direction[0]);

and modified the fragment shader with this:
uniform vec3 light_direction;
const vec3 LightDirection = normalize(light_direction);

Still getting incorrect results.

Comment: The picture looks more like there's a bad vertex or normal in your geometry.

Answer (score 2):

Let me elaborate a bit more on dari's comment.

Your normal vector is multiplied with a normal matrix derived from the `view*model` matrix (called `modelview` in your application). Multiplying vertices with the model matrix transforms them from **local-space** to **world-space** and multiplying vertices in **world-space** with a view matrix transforms them to **view-space** coordinates. In your case, you transformed the normal vector with the model **and** view matrix; this means that your normal vectors are in view-space (their direction, as seen from the viewer's perspective: the camera).

Now, you specified the light's direction vector `LightDirection` in world-space (its direction is how you want it to be in the global world right? No need to transform it in any way with a model matrix).

When calculating diffuse/specular lighting, you want your direction/position vectors to all reside in the same coordinate space, otherwise you're doing calculations between different spaces which generates weird results. Since your `LightDirection` is in *world-space* and your `Normal` in *view-space* you get weird results.

What you thus need to do to solve your issue is either:

- Transform `LightDirection` to *view-space* by multiplying it with the view matrix (not `modelview` since that contains both the model **and** view matrix).
- **or** calculate your normal matrix from just the model matrix (not `modelview`) so your normal vector will end up in *world-space* just like `LightDirection` currently is.

The important thing is that both vectors are in the same space (can be either world or view, whatever you prefer).

**Note** that this applies to when you want to give the impression the camera is moving while the objects are stationary (allowing you to move to unlit sides of your objects); see Reto Koradi's comment below.

Comment: I don't think this is the only thing that makes sense. It really depends on what you want. Sometimes you want to transform the objects, and keep the light source stationary. This gives the impression that the objects are moving around, and the camera is stationary (together with the light sources). Other times you want to give the impression that the camera is moving around, and the objects are stationary. In this case, you want to transform the light sources with the objects. What the OP implemented is the first scenario, and completely valid.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the first scenario, you're talking about a light source that remains at the same world-space coordinates/direction regardless of the camera's orientation/movement (like a glowing orb of light always at the top-right of the screen for example)?

Comment: It's kind of hard to explain without pictures. Imagine the camera and light source being stationary, and objects moving around in response to user input. It's a very common usage model. In fact it's often much more useful, because you always get good, consistent lighting. If you let the camera move around, but leave the light in place, the objects are dark when you move to the side of the object opposite from the light.

Comment: Ahh I get what you mean now, thanks :) I'll update the answer to reflect this

Comment: I have to mention that the problem was with loading normals from the object file (after that I got my expected result: the object rotates and the camera and light source remain stationary), although your explanations really helped me understand what's going on. Before that I didn't really get the point in having separate matrices for both model and view transformations so I mixed them into one matrix, but now I do.